# How to migrate to co-routines instead of Rx java in android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

***I have a repository class where I am getting a data from the server***

**`StudentRepo.kt`**

```
class StudentRepo (sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences){

    private val liveDataRandomStudent = MutableLiveData<List<StudentModel>>()
    private val liveDataGroupingStudent = MutableLiveData<List<StudentModel>>()
    private val liveProgress = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    private val liveErrorMessage = MutableLiveData<String>()

    var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = sharedPreferences

    private var compositeDisposable : CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()


    /************************************* MUTABLE DATA ********************************************/
    /** LIVE DATA: - Live data for API response **/
    fun getStudentListRandom(dataService: ApiInterface): MutableLiveData<List<StudentModel>> {
        compositeDisposable.add(getServerDataDisposableRandomStudent(dataService))
        return liveDataRandomStudent
    }

    /** LIVE DATA: - Live data for progress response **/
    fun getLiveProgress(): MutableLiveData<Boolean> {
        return liveProgress
    }

    /** LIVE DATA: - Live data for error response **/
    fun getLiveErrorMessage(): MutableLiveData<String> {
        return liveErrorMessage
    }
    /************************************* MUTABLE DATA ********************************************/

    /************************************* DISPOSABLES - For - API  ********************************/
     fun getServerDataDisposableRandomStudent(dataService: ApiInterface): Disposable {

        val classId = sharedPreferences[CLASS_ID, ""]!!
        val accessToken = sharedPreferences[SharedPrefHelper.ACCESS_TOKEN, ""]!!

        liveProgress.postValue(true)
        return dataService.getStudentsRx(accessToken,classId)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object: DisposableSingleObserver<StudentResultResponse>(), Observer<StudentResultResponse> {

                override fun onSuccess(response: StudentResultResponse) {
                    Timber.d("")
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                   Timber.d("")
                    liveProgress.postValue(false)
                    liveErrorMessage.postValue(e.message)
                }

                override fun onComplete() {
                    Timber.d("")
                    liveProgress.postValue(false)
                }

                override fun onNext(response: StudentResultResponse) {
                    Timber.d("")
                    liveDataRandomStudent.postValue(response.data)
                }

            })
    }

    /************************************* DISPOSABLES - For - API  ********************************/


    /** Clear disposables  */
    fun clearDisposables() {
        if (!compositeDisposable.isDisposed) {
            compositeDisposable.dispose()
        }
    }


}
```

---

**What I have used:**

1. Retrofit
2. Rxjava

**What I am trying to do:**  How to use co-routines instead of RxJava here

Comment: Do you want to convert the code into coroutine specific one or want a adapter for this rx code for using this with coroutines?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu .. Looking for `a adapter for this rx code for using this with coroutines`

Comment: @AnimeshSahu .... Both Solutions would be great to learn both :)

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Use retrofit version 2.6.0+, that supports the suspend modifier in your api interface definition out of the box.

Option 2: Use the rx2 to coroutines methods in [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/reactive/kotlinx-coroutines-rx2)

I personally recommend option 1, to prevent unnecessary overhead caused by introducing more dependencies than needed and less object creation for performance

Hope that helps!